# NG SERVE command issue

Tags: javascript, angular, configuration, frontend

I got problem with running my angular app via ng serve.

After hours and hours of fighting with angular (had many problems with angular cli) I am able to generate project without errors. I imported this project to IntelliJ and want to run  by ng serve command.

after call  ng serve   got this:
The program 'ng' is currently not installed. You can install it by typing:
sudo apt install ng-common

Any ideas?

Comment: When you said you successfully generated a project, did you do it with `ng generate`? If you did, there's no reason why `ng serve` shouldn't also work. Check whether your current Node installation has `@angular/cli` installed. If not, install it again: `npm i -g @angular/cli` and then try once more.

Comment: I did use : `ng new TestApp` Project was generated. And after this I wanted run   `ng serve` and got this `The program ng is currently not installed. You can install it by typing: sudo apt install ng-common`. 
I will check your solution after work and let you know.

Comment: @derirative23 is your angular CLI installed globally

Comment: @derirative23 : Have you tried https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/7735#issuecomment-399445588

Comment: @Shashank Vivek I think I installed angular CLI with  'npm install -g @angular/cli'. But without globally installation I would be able to create project by 'ng new TestApp'
I had issues with permission and I tried to do something with ~/.profil but I'm not sure right now.
I will check your solution after work and let you know

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hope this guide will help you to create a project without errors.

```
1. first open terminal or console window and run, npm install -g @angular/cli
2. To create a new workspace and initial starter app, ng new my-app-name
3. Go to my-app-name folder, cd my-app-name
4. Launch the server by using the CLI command, ng serve --o (--o to open in browser)
```

Comment: So it solved my problem but I also needed to Manually change npm’s default directory link is below
[link] (https://docs.npmjs.com/resolving-eacces-permissions-errors-when-installing-packages-globally#manually-change-npms-default-directory)
Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you are running the "ng serve" command from inside the root directory of your angular project (the cli path is correct).

This error occurres because your command line interface cannot make sense of the command and whilst "ng new project" may execute from practically anywhere, other ng commands such as "ng serve" can only execute from within the project root directory.